# Double spacing within the caption of a figure

Tags: captions, memoir, subfloats, line-spacing

I am using the `memoir` class on my thesis and I have the `\DoubleSpacing` command in my document to set up double spacing through the document. This works great.

However, I have a figure with subfigures  using `\subbottom[]{\includegraphics{}}` command, and the text in the caption shows with single spacing. How can I activate double spacing in the caption?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just insert the command `\DoubleSpacing` at the start of the caption material as well. To avoid getting an error message, also provide a short caption as the second, optional argument (in square brackets) to the `\caption` command. The contents of the short caption will be used when the List of Figures is generated with the `\listoffigures` command. In the MWE below, the short caption consists of just the first three words of the long caption.

Even if you're absolutely sure that you are *not* going to generate a list of figures for your document, you still need to provide a short caption. (It could be as simple as `[]` if you won't be generating a list of figures.) Otherwise, you'll get an error message, which is caused by the `\DoubleSpacing` command and by LaTeX's behind-the-scenes attempt to create a "short caption" automatically from the long caption if a short caption is not supplied explicitly.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\DoubleSpacing
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
\caption[Nam dui ligula]{\DoubleSpacing\lipsum[2]}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

**Aside**: It's usually considered to be more reader-friendly to provide (i) a fairly short caption header (i.e., one that fits on a single line) and (ii) a longer, self-contained description of the figure's (or table's) contents elsewhere in the figure (table) environment.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Where are the short captions printed? I don't see them anywhere.

Comment: The short captions are used by the `\listoffigures` command to generate the contents of the "List of Figures" part of the document. I didn't include this command in the MWE as it wasn't clear to me if you needed one for your document. The point is that even if you're not going to generate a List of Figures, you still need to provide a short caption because otherwise LaTeX will break down with an error message that's caused by the presence of the `\DoubleSpacing` command inside the long caption.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I had the same issue and didn't want to edit each caption individually.

There is a much more elegant solution in memoir: the `\DoubleSpacing*` command. But what if you don't want *everything* double spaced, only the body and captions? Then you'll need to control them separately.

Here's my memoir-friendly solution in a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx,kantlipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\DoubleSpacing

\DeclareCaptionJustification{double}{\DoubleSpacing}
\captionsetup{justification=double}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\kant*[1]\footnote{single spaced footnote: \kant[4]}
\kant[2-3]
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{\kant[1]}\label{tab:mytable}
Some table comes here
\end{table}

\kant[4-8]
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{\kant[2]}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now you can control the captions separately from other text.